# How to create a MySQL database (table) in Go and perform CRUD operations

Tags: mysql, database, api, go, crud

I have imported the drivers from 
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql 
and have successfully established connection to the database.
I just want to start creating a table and be able to update, fetch and delete data from it
Other resources I've seen seem to skip this part or are just unclear about it (they seem to start fetching the data and I'm like ..where did the data come from, how did they create it) and I just want clear explanations thanks.

```
// main.go
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Update 16/05/2020:
It turns out that I never even knew a database server had to be running in the first place as @mkopriva pointed out in the comments (I guess this was the initial source of my challenge...now I'm like what else was I suppose to even connect to...duh...lol)
P.S. firewall was not an issue in my case.

Comment: Please share what code you've written so far and what's the error you're getting.

Comment: I'm not getting errors actually...I just want to know how to create the data in the database

Comment: The `database/sql` package is pretty bare bones. There's no convenient function for creating tables (or any other specific query). You can just look up how to execute a query. Then send a CREATE TABLE statement, etc. The docs: https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/

Comment: Or, if you just want to get data in MySQL, you can use the MySQL CLI to execute some statements (or run an .sql file) to set up a table and insert some data so your application can have something to read. I think the reason the tutorials skip this is that they are about Golang and not MySQL. They assume you already know how MySQL works or else you wouldn't want to connect to it. You might want to check out some MySQL tutorials to learn how to insert some test data for your application to read.

Comment: I recomend you use an ORM for manage relational databases, it exists one very good for golang, you can get it in https://gorm.io/

Comment: @janmbaco thanks but I just want it to be done without gorm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the methods [`Exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec), [`Query`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query), and [`QueryRow`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryRow) that are provided by `*sql.DB` to send your SQL commands to the connected database.

```
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    _, err := db.Exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, some_text TEXT NOT NULL)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Create
    res, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO mytable (some_text) VALUES (?)", "hello world")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // get the id of the newly inserted record
    id, err := res.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Read
    var someText string
    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT some_text FROM mytable WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1", id)
    if err := row.Scan(&someText); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(someText)

    // Update
    _, err = db.Exec("UPDATE mytable SET some_text = ? WHERE id = ?", "Hello, 世界", id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Delete
    _, err = db.Exec("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = ?", id)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error...```panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it``` I am using Windows 10

Comment: @Bruno this is your question's first sentence: *"I have imported the drivers from github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql and have **successfully established connection** to the database."* It's either one or the other.

Comment: @Bruno if you have problems successfully establishing a connection to your mysql database you should open a new question, the current question is about how to execute CRUD operations.

Comment: Alright... however, this error just occurred after running the code to create a table ```_, err := db.Exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, some_text TEXT NOT NULL)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }``` if I comment that portion out, it doesn't throw the error

Comment: @Bruno better yet, before creating a new question you should search the web a bit, there's probably something out there that matches your current difficulty.

Comment: Oh I have and I have applied the solution of disabling my firewall but still the error persists.

Comment: @Bruno The [`db.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open) documentation states: *"Open may just validate its arguments without creating a connection to the database. To verify that the data source name is valid, call Ping."*, so to check that you are actually able to connect to the database, call [`Ping`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Ping), I've updated the code in the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Bruno and is your db server running? Are you able to connect to it with the cli? And when you're connecting with the cli are you supplying any credentials? To connect to the db are you using the *literal* string that's in the question? i.e. is your username `user` and your password `password`? Or, if not, are you replacing them, in your actual code, with the actual username and password values? Is `dbname` the name of an actual database on your server?

Comment: For the credentials, yes..the literal strings are the credentials however I'm quite lost at the first question "is the db server running?" Am I supposed to run the database some how else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213844/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-bruno).

Comment: @Bruno "somehow else" as compared to what? as compared to `sql.Open`? Well `sql.Open` tries to *connect* to an already running database server, that's what the "connection" means. Your program connects to another program. sql.Open does not spin up a new server and then connects to it, no, it expects a server to be already up & running at the location specified by the connection string.